# Does MEAN.js has something similar to Sails.js blueprints?

Tags: api, sails.js, mean-stack, meanjs, scaffolding

Sails.js has a functionality called Blueprints that automatically creates API code that can search, paginate, sort, filter, create, destroy, update based on a model.
Can I achieve the same with MEAN.js?

Answer (score 0):

**No**. I tried looking, it doesn't look like MEAN.js has blueprints-like feature.

However, if you start implementing routes as you need and abstract common functionality, it should be good.

Sails blueprints are only good as starting point, in decently complex application you have to write own controller code.

PS: I don't use MEAN.js (use Sails though).